# JOGL - Texture shows blue scale

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I'm trying to make a game in Java OpenGL (JOGL), but I have a problem with textures.
When I draw a quad with a texture, the only thing I see is the image in blue scale.
The following is my code:

```
Texture grass;
// public void init() in Base class that implements GLEventListener
try {
    grass = TextureIO.newTexture(new File("src/com/jeroendonners/main/grass.png"), false);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To render a quad with this texture I use the following code:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
gl.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);
this.grass.bind(gl);
gl.glBegin(gl.GL_QUADS);
gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
gl.glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
gl.glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
gl.glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
gl.glEnd();
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296503/texture-has-only-blue-hue-when-using-glteximage2d) that I have to use GL_BGR instead of the default GL_RGB, but since that question initializes textures in a different way, I don't know what to do with it.

Maybe a note: I am using an old version of JOGL, 1.0 I think. That's because I had a course on school with this version.

Comment: Do you have texturing enabled? You'll need something like `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`.

Comment: Yes, I indeed forgot to say that. It's called right after loading the textures. (At the end of public void init())

Comment: In JOGL 1, TextureIO uses AWT under the hood to load the texture data whereas in JOGL 2 it uses PNGJ. Switching to JOGL 2 would probably fix your bug but please post a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example: http://www.sscce.org